# Has Export to AI (Adobe Illustrator) changed at ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.2, illustrator

In the past when I would export vector layers from ArcGIS each layer would be nested in a group with a clipping path over the top.

Now when I Export to AI from 10.2 that layer's features are 5-6 layers deep.

Did this software behaviour change at 10.2?

[image]

Comment: I suspect few people have access to Adobe Illustrator and both ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 SP1 and 10.2 in order to test your question.  Have you logged it with Esri Technical Support?

Comment: I have the same problem with my Arcgis 10.2 and illustrator CS5.1. With arcgis 9.3 it worked fine, but since I upgrade my arcgis to 10.2 it is a mess to modify maps in illustrator. Have you find a seting/option to change that? Thanks!

Comment: @PierreP .. Thanks for weighing in on this. I contacted ESRI and they told me that it was a problem with Illustrator. It is obviously not an Illustrator problem and is a problem with 10.2. I've been dragging the final <Clip Group> up to the top level and deleting the others. Its a temporary fix but works for now.

Comment: @PierreP I think you should add your confirmation that you observed this software behaviour change between 9.3 and 10.2 as an Answer but to avoid it being converted into a Comment just say what you observe rather than ask a question within your Answer.

Comment: Not in 10.2 but in 10.3 yes. Now there is only one group by layer or by label class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Comments, I think this is a Question that should be the responsibility of your local **[Esri Technical Support](http://support.esri.com/en/)** to try and resolve.

With @PierreP agreeing that the software behaviour change exists there should be impetus for them to resolve it.

I would be keen for you to include the words written when Esri Support told you that "it was a problem with Illustrator" into your Question, along with your reason for thinking it "is obviously not an Illustrator problem".